# Code Chef: https://www.codechef.com/SEPT16/problems/CHFNFRN

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was partially able to solve this (failed on one test case). I could not figure out that one test case that would break my algorithm.

> Given a graph G = (V, E), determine, whether its vertices can be partitioned into two sets V1 and V2, such that both V1 and V2 form a clique in G.

CodeChef: [Problem Link](https://www.codechef.com/SEPT16/problems/CHFNFRN)

Algorithm..

a) Sort the friends in increasing order of their connections. (do not count connections with the self)

b) Set Table A (TA) and Table B (TB) both as empty.

```
bool current_placed = false
For (loop) all the friends in the sorted list do the below

  current_placed = false

  if (TA empty) {

      Place current friend on TA

      current_placed = true

  } else {

      // If current friend is connected with all the people already seated on TA.

     if(current friend connected with all on TA){
        Place current friend on TA too.
        current_placed = true
     }
  }

  if(current_placed == false){

     If (TB empty) {

        Place current friend on TB

        current_placed = true

     } else {

       // If current friend is connected with all the people already seated on TB
       if(current friend connected with all on TB){
          Place current friend on TB too.
          current_placed = true;
       } 
    } 
  } 

  if(current_placed == false) {

    ans => NO

    break starting for loop

  } 
// For loop ends

if(current_placed == true)
{
   ans => YES
}
```

My Code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> VI;
typedef set<int> SI;
typedef vector<VI> VVI;
typedef pair<int,int> PII;
typedef vector<PII> VPII;

bool mat[1004][1004];
int contacts[10004];

bool mycomp(const PII &a, const PII &b){
     return a.second < b.second;
}

int main(){

    int tcs, num_friends, num_pairs;
    int a, b;
    cin >> tcs;

    while(tcs--){

        SI TA, TB;
        cin >> num_friends >> num_pairs;

        memset(mat, 0, sizeof(bool)*1004*1004);
        memset(contacts, 0, sizeof(int)*10004);

        for(int i=0; i<num_pairs; i++){
            cin >> a >> b;
            mat[a][b] = true;
            mat[b][a] = true;
        }

        for(int r=1; r<=num_friends; r++){
            for(int c=1; c<=num_friends; c++){
                if(mat[r][c] and r != c){
                    contacts[r] += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        bool placed = false, connected;

        VPII myvec;
        for(int i=1; i<=num_friends; i++)
            myvec.push_back(PII(i,contacts[i]));

        sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), mycomp);
        VPII :: iterator it;

        for(it = myvec.begin(); it != myvec.end(); ++it){
            PII p = *it;
            //cout << p.first << " " << p.second << endl;
            int i = p.first;    

            placed = false;

            if(TA.empty()){
                TA.insert(i);
                placed = true;
            } else {
                connected = true;
                SI :: iterator itr;
                for(itr = TA.begin(); itr != TA.end(); ++itr){
                    if(mat[i][*itr] == false){
                        connected = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }   
                if(connected == true){
                    TA.insert(i);
                    placed = true;
                }
            }           

            if(placed == false){
                if(TB.empty()){
                    TB.insert(i);
                    placed = true;
                } else {
                    connected = true;
                    SI :: iterator itr;
                    for(itr = TB.begin(); itr != TB.end(); ++itr){
                        if(mat[i][*itr] == false){
                            connected = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(connected == true){
                        TB.insert(i);
                        placed = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(placed == false){
                cout << "NO" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(placed == true) 
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        /*
        SI :: iterator itr;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "SET A" << endl;
        for(itr = TA.begin(); itr != TA.end(); ++itr)
            cout << *itr << " ";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "SET B" << endl;
        for(itr = TB.begin(); itr != TB.end(); ++itr)
            cout << *itr << " ";
        cout << endl; */
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the Editorial of this problem? https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/84915/chfnfrn-editorial

Comment: Yes. Editorial suggests a different approach to solving this. But I was pretty convinced by the correctness of my approach too.

Comment: In what order do you place people with the same number of connections?

Comment: The order in which I take the input. i.e after sorting the relative ordering of the people with the same connections do not change. So whichever order I get the input.
@user58697 is there any hint lurking in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Not so much of a hint but a refutation.

Consider the 6 vertices graph:

```
(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)
(4, 5), (5, 6), (4, 6)
(1, 4), (2, 3), (5, 6)
```

where each person has exactly 3 connections. Notice that the graph has 2 cliques (`1, 2, 3` and `4, 5, 6`).

Now lets say a person 1 comes first, and you place him at Table A. A person 4 comes second, and your algorithm also places him at Table A. After that no placement is possible.

I don't really see the way to repair this greedy placement.

Comment: (Thanks for taking out time in devising a test case)

My algorithm does not consider duplicate edges. It would sort the above as below

Friend Connections
   2     -      2
   3     -      2
   5     -      2
   6     -      2
   1     -      3
   4     -      3 
So the sequence of placing would be 2->3->5->6->1->4. I ran the above and it correctly places them. :(